# Unknown MSSQL data spaces/storages

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to create another table and specify a data space, when I couldn't avoid noticing these weird elements on the list:

[image]

The thing is, I didn't create them.
My storages are "PRIMARY" and "HDD_GROUP".

How did these appear? My googling skills are failing me, but that is a topic is not for today's jedi consult.

How are they used? Where are they located? What happens if I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow it down, try a new query window in system management studio 
`select * from sys.data_spaces`

Reference the docs here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-data-spaces-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

That should lead you towards what they are.

Comment: Thank you. They are full-text partition-things, used by mssql to index texts.